# Connecting to raspberry pi to set up wireless access point

Tags: raspbian, networking, ssh, wireless, hostapd

I am using the following link :https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/ to set up my raspberry pi to act like a wireless router. So far I have installed raspbian on a sd card. I don't have access to an external monitor or a keyboard. I have access to a ubuntu laptop. I want to use the commands on the tutorial to set up the pi but how do I connect to pi in the first place. This is the first time I am doing this and I have no idea. I have an ethernet cable and wifi access that is again provided by a raspberry pi that was already set up by somebody else. How can I connect to the raspberry pi in the terminal to execute the commands? Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear. The Pi makes a poor router and if I wanted to setup an Access Point I would follow the Foundation tutorial. Your first task should be to configure Raspbian. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)  You COULD follow "Headless Raspbian WiFi Setup"  but it is better to connect to your router via Ethernet.

Comment: Okay the thing is I have a terminal that says my username. How do I connect to the pi so that I can get pi@raspberrypi or something like that so that I can control the pi from my laptop terminal and use the commands.

Comment: In other words how do I ssh into a headless pi. I have an ethernet cable if it helps.

Comment: `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` or `ssh pi@<ip address of your pi>`.

Answer (score 1):

**ENABLE SSH**

[SSH](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/unix.md) is what you're looking for. If you connect your RPI ethernet port to your router you can use `arp -a` (linux, mac) to see all IP addresses on your network. You will likely see your pi as  `pi (192.168.1.15)` or something along those lines.

Once you find the pi IP you can connect to the raspberry pi using the `ssh` command. When connecting to the raspberry pi a prompt will ask you for a password (it is usually `raspberry` on raspbian OS).

```
ssh pi@192.168.1.15
```

If this doesn't work, SSH might not be enabled. You can take your SD card and put create an empty file with the name SSH at the boot directory.

Comment: When I execute `apr -a` on my Raspberry Pi I get: `-bash: apr: command not found`. Did you mean `ip a`? But this only shows the IP addresses of the local interfaces not all IP addresses on the network.

Comment: forgive me typo. try `arp -a`

Comment: Ah.. you mean asking the local arp cache. But this will not give you all IP addresses on your network. It will only show addresses that where addressed the last 5 minutes. If you haven't addressed the RasPi the last 5 minutes (e.g. with ping) it isn't shown in the arp cache. Using `nmap` seems to be better.